# How eosbetdice listen to new active bet and then push an resolvebet action?

Tags: nodeos, eosjs

I guess this is done off-chain? they should have some daemon to monitor actions. Once a new active bet is created, the daemon will sign the seed hash with the private key and then push an resolvebet .
My question is if there is any existing tool / daemon can help to achieve this?  (listen to new action pushed and then push and action)

Answer (score 1):

One way they could be doing this is through the mongodb plugin, and use a separate server or application to monitor the changes in the mongodb entry

Also, the new action(new bet) can be created by sending in EOS to the contract, which can activate a set of behaviors through the smart contract.

I'm not entirely familiar with the eosbetdice source code, could you provide it for better response?

Comment: Thanks. I think i will just use a simple nodejs program with eosjs to monitor the activebets table :)) For the source code: https://gitlab.com/EOSBetCasino/eosbetdice_public/blob/master/EOSBetDice.cpp

Comment: Nodejs and eosjs always works beautifully